# Do you know how to create a custom domain name with azure command line?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-cdn, azure-cli2, azure-dns

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/?view=azure-cli-latest

```
1.Resource Group                        |  az group create -l westeurope -n Domains

2.CDN > profile  > create               |  az cdn profile create -g Domains -n HomeProfile --sku Premium_Verizon

3.CDN > endpoint > create               |  az cdn endpoint create -g Domains -n HomeEndpoint --profile-name HomeProfile --origin www.home1991-2000.com

4.DNS > Zones > create                  |  az network dns zone create -g Domains -n www.home1991-2000.com

5.DNS > Record sets > CNAME > create    |  az network dns record-set cname create -g Domains -z www.home1991-2000.com -n HomeRecordSet
 
6.eventgrid > domain > create           |  az eventgrid domain create -g Domains --name home1991-2000 -l westeurope

7.CDN > custom-domain > create          |  az cdn custom-domain create -g Domains --endpoint-name HomeEndpoint --profile-name HomeProfile -n home1991-2000-name --hostname www.home1991-2000.com
```

I'm receive these bad request. Can anyone help ?

BadRequest - We couldn't find a DNS record for custom domain that points to endpoint. To map a domain to this endpoint, create a CNAME record with your DNS provider for custom domain that points to endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain#create-a-cname-dns-record):

> Before you can use a custom domain with an Azure CDN endpoint, you
> must first create a canonical name (CNAME) record with your domain
> provider to point to your CDN endpoint. A CNAME record is a type of
> DNS record that maps a source domain name to a destination domain
> name. For Azure CDN, the source domain name is your custom domain name
> and the destination domain name is your CDN endpoint hostname. After
> Azure CDN verifies the CNAME record that you create, traffic addressed
> to the source custom domain (such as [www.contoso.com](http://www.contoso.com)) is routed to the
> specified destination CDN endpoint hostname (such as
> contoso.azureedge.net).

Therefore, as the error message points out, you will need to create a CNAME record with your DNS provider for your custom domain that points to your CDN endpoint, i.e., `HomeEndpoint.azureedge.net`.

As a pre-req, in order to use Azure DNS for your custom domain, you must first [delegate your domain to Azure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-delegate-domain-azure-dns). If you do not already have a custom domain, you must first [purchase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-custom-dns-buy-domain) one with a domain provider.

Once this is done, you can [associate the custom domain with your CDN endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain#map-the-permanent-custom-domain).

**Note:**
The [`az network dns record-set cname create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/dns/record-set/cname?view=azure-cli-latest#az_network_dns_record_set_cname_create) command only creates an **empty** CNAME record set. You might want to use [`az network dns record-set cname set-record`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/dns/record-set/cname?view=azure-cli-latest#az_network_dns_record_set_cname_set_record) instead to actually also set the **value** of a CNAME record.

References:

- [Tutorial: Add a custom domain to your Azure CDN endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain)
- [Use Azure DNS to provide custom domain settings for an Azure CDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-custom-domain#azure-cdn)